# How can I get Google PR history of exact site?

Tags: google, pagerank

As some pages of my site have gotten n/a of PR from Google, I need to see the history of PR's changing for those and other pages to estimate the situation and decide what to do.
Where can I get the past PR's of exact site/page?

Comment: I do not believe that you can get the PR of any particular page, just for the site overall. Is there a tool you are using to help us comment better?

Comment: have you tried moz tool bar or moz seo tools

Comment: @Marian: You really should forget this PageRank concept.

Comment: @closetnoc: Each page can have it's own PR. `/example` can be a 4 while `/garbage` could be a 1.

Comment: Of course there is PageRank for pages, that is why it's called PageRank and not SiteRank (only possible to see the green toolbar PR however which is not a true, real-time reflection of the actual PR value). It is not possible to see a history of PageRank change for pages on a domain however unless you build a tool specifically to store PR change in your own database. I'm unaware of anyone else that has built a tool such as this.

Comment: @melisagaza What tool do you mean exactly? MOZ has many SEO-tools.

Comment: @Zistolen Of course, but in this case I want to check my site for automatic filter from Google. That's why I need to see historic PR of those inner pages and to make a conclusion what to do to improve  it.

Comment: @Martijn I am not a noob. You need to read my comment again slowly. PageRank originally was only applied to the site overall- hence PageRank for any site as a metric. It is carryover that Google actually regrets. My comment referred to getting individual PR for any page. This is not data publicly available and no tool can get this- they can only apply their own metrics.

Comment: @closetnoc We have no any tool for this. I have tried some online services, but they are not working on this, just show "no info".
I think, probably, there is a crawler on the Internet which can return me the historical PR of particular pages.

Comment: There are too many bad online tools. The problem with them is that the web-o-sphere is so large that that they cannot really know enough about any site. For example, when I had over 8000 verified backlinks, most reported that I had 6 or 4. My site is fairly old and this condition has always existed and remains today. I am pretty sure there is no tool that will give you real-time metrics, but perhaps clues. MOZ as an online tool seems to be the best. I also use SEO Power Suite which does not rely on online services, but can take a long time to run. It may not give you what you want, but try it.

Comment: @Marian I went to http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/ earlier. It is another slow and incomplete site, but it does add value metrics per page that can be trusted at least. It is a MOZ site. See if there is anything of value there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that many pages on your site have no PageRank is that Google hasn't released data for any pages created since December 2013.     Google occasionally creates a snapshot of all the PageRank on the internet.   That snapshot is what you see in the Google Toolbar and other PageRank checkers.

Google doesn't offer a history of PageRank, just the value as of the last data refresh.   The only way to have gotten the historical values would have been to record them yourself.

Because the toolbar PageRank data is so stale, you shouldn't worry about n/a PageRank.   There are other metrics that indicate that Google is happy with your site and your pages.   I stopped paying much attention to PageRank and I use indicators like:

- How often does Googlebot crawl the page?
- Is the page indexed when I search for its URL or for its title?
- Is the page ranking well for any keywords?
- Is the page getting referrals from the Google search engine?

Comment: "Google hasn't released data for any pages created since December 2013" - I know this. I was only troubled with the situation, that some my pages had had PR not n/a, and then site got a manual penalty. After that the PR on some pages became n/a. The penalty was removed, but the n/a PR is still there.